# getting key when value is known in dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a list of dictionary and i am searching for a key based on value. How to do this?

`"someId"` returns an error:

> "The given key was not present in the dictionary."

So if I give value "Ann", then I would expect the function to return key "30".

Each Item in the dictionary is like this

```
    item 1
    [0] {[someid,30]}
    [1] {[somename,"Ann"]}
    [2] {[someaddress,"3, Carl House, UK"]}
```

```
private static int getmyId(string name)
{
    ...
    List<Dictionary<string, string>> myList = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

    foreach (Dictionary<string, string> item in myList)
    {           
        if (item.ContainsValue(name))
        {
              myID = item["Someid"];
        }
    }
    ...
    return myID
}
```

Comment: The function you posted doesn't return anything.  Additionally, it doesn't even make sense.  Did you forget to include the whole thing?

Comment: Why do you do `string x = item["SomeName"];` in all dictionaries?

Comment: @user1651888 this doesn't look like a elegant solution to a problem. If you provide more detail on what you are trying to achive we can help find a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

To get a key from a value in a dictionary is a bit tricky because values can be reused.  Therefore you either need to return a list of keys, or have the function only return the first matching key.

Here's both methods as static functions:

```
static List<string> GetKeysFromValue(Dictionary<string,string> dict, string val)
{
    if(!dict.ContainsValue(val))
        return new List<string>(); //return EMPTY list for no matching keys

    return dict.Where(kv => kv.Value.Equals(val)).Select(kv => kv.Key).ToList();
}
```

To explain the above:

1. We get all the key-value pairs in the dictionary that have the matching value using the `Where` linq function.
2. Now that we have an `IEnumerable` of `KeyValuePair` objects we then call `Select`, which is a linq function that performs projections.  This takes the keys out of the returned `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair>`.
3. Finally, we convert the `IEnumerable<string>` to a list by calling `.ToList()`

To get only the first matching key, you can do this:

```
static string GetFirstKeyFromValue(Dictionary<string,string> dict, string val)
{
    if(!dict.ContainsValue(val))
        return null; //return null because nothing matched.

    return dict.FirstOrDefault(kv => kv.Value.Equals(val)).Key;
}
```

`FirstOrDefault` will return the first matching key value pair from the dictionary, or `null` if none are found.  Since we already checked that it will return something earlier with the `ContainsValue()` method, we can safely just call `Key` to get the value of the key property.

I also wanted to point out that based on your method signature that you posted you are treating your `Dictionary<string,string>` as a `List<string>`.  A dictionary does not have indexes, hence the use of a user-defined key type.  Therefore there is no reason to return an `int` since there is no index.  Instead you should be returning the key, which you posted is a string.

Comment: Nice answer and description.  My suggestions: (1) that GetKeysFromValue should return a new List<string>() instead of null, and (2) GetFirstKeyFromValue should simply call GetKeysFromValue.

Comment: Since FirstOrDefault may return null, might want to check before returning .Key. Aside from that, this is probably the easiest way to get the potential keys from a value.

Comment: @RickDavin I wrote both of them out in case OP doesn't actually need multiple keys.  Also I thought it would be more helpful to show both ways instead of calling the other function to show how it would be done.  Regarding returning an empty list instead of null:  On second look, I agree.  I'll update that.

Comment: @bsayegh No it won't return null in this case because we did a check to make sure that a matching value exists first.  I explained this in my answer.

Comment: But in that case you could just call .First. I am just nitpicking now.

Comment: @bsayegh No, you can't.  `.First()` will throw an exception if nothing is found, which is not only unnecessary, but it will slow the application down every time nothing is found.  Essentially, you can either do the check before, such as in my example, or check for null after as you suggested.  It doesn't really matter since they both produce the exact same result.  Doing it afterwards might be faster, since the search only happens once, but the functionality is the same and I wanted to be verbose in my example.

Comment: Im saying that if you check beforehand you can use .First. If you aren't checking beforehand, use FirstOrDefault. My initial suggestion of checking for null was debunked by checking for the value before finding the key.

Comment: @bsayegh Ah, I see what you're saying.  Not going to update it now since it's trivial, but point taken.